# Use vue component in other vue component file

Tags: vue.js

I tried to use a vue component(Global.vue) in other component(App.vue), but there

> Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

error.

**Global.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div class="global-view">
    <p>Global </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'global'
}
</script>
```

**App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <global></global>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>
```

**main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.component('global', require('./components/Global'))

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Comment: See this  https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues/127  - perhaps the require statement is casuing the problem, Johnathan suggests using import instead.

Comment: @RichardMatsen yeah, import works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the component within the component file that you want to use it in.

`import Global from './components/Global'

From there you need to add a new key inside your components option that will "register" the component.

Here is what you want your app component to look like.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <global></global>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Global from './components/Global

export default {
  name: 'app'
  components: {
    'global': Global,
  }
}
</script>
```

`<global></global>` should be able to render at this point.

Comment: OP is already exposing the component globally using Vue.component.

Comment: @Bert: OP still needs to register that component to be used by the `new Vue` instance by adding it to the `components` object.

Comment: No, he does not, when it is registered globally.

Comment: @Bert Doesn't template in .vue files get compiled to a render function, so Global.vue needs to know about custom components up front? Registering them later, globally, will not help with that.

Comment: Single file components do get compiled. They get compiled into an object that you can *either* register globally, or import locally using the components property. See this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nkwk445k1m). The real issue in the question is the difference between import and require.

Answer (score 1):

I use import instead of require(in main.js) and it works for me:

```
import Global from './components/Global.vue
Vue.component('global', Global)`
```