# VueJS error: "Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I struggle to understand the component and template system in VueJS. I downloaded the [VuetifyJS PWA example template](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/pwa) and tried to replace the complete content of **[Hello.vue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/pwa/blob/master/template/src/components/Hello.vue)** with the content of the VuetifyJS [**google-contacts.vue**](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/docs/blob/master/examples/layouts/google-contacts.vue) example template.
I got this error message after `npm run dev` on `localhost:8080`:

```
> vue.esm.js?65d7:578 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
found in
---> <Hello> at /home/a/my-project/src/components/Hello.vue
       <App> at /home/a/my-project/src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

Why is it not possible to just replace the `<template></template>` content and what do I need to change to use the **google-contacts.vue** template content instead of the **Hello.vue** content?

Comment: From what I've seen, there are typically two ways to handle Vue components: 1) the classic way in which you use the `template` property of a component, and 2) exporting individual components and then importing them later. It sounds like the second is what you're aiming for and that you're doing it incorrectly. Unfortunately we can't determine whether or not this is the case. Please provide code snippets so that we may have a clearer picture of your problem.

Comment: I linked the code I used in my question (bold text) and the complete template too. (These are both examples of VuetifyJS )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use vue component in other vue component file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384186/use-vue-component-in-other-vue-component-file)

Comment: @ramazan793 I tried the suggest solution but it didn't work. Error: `<hello> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at /home/a/my-project/src/App.vue
       <Root>`

Comment: @Tom try to register your component globally in main.js: 
`import Hello from '~/components/hello.vue'
Vue.component('Hello', Hello);` As in the second answer to that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just followed the process and it works ok for me, so I'm guessing it's most likely a miss-step in your build, but so far can't reproduce it.

Note, it looks like [docs/examples/layouts/google-contacts.vue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/docs/blob/master/examples/layouts/google-contacts.vue) is a replacement for the overall page layout rather than an individual component (thinking along the lines @B.Fleming mentions in comments), so it's more appropriate to replace `App.vue` than `Hello.vue`.

This is what I originally did (not reading your post thoroughly). But subsequently replacing `Hello.vue` gives me the same working Google Contacts page.

Comment: It was a build problem. Thank you